# Silverstripe and ProxySQL

Tags: silverstripe, proxysql

Has any one had any success setting ProxySQL up to work with Silverstripe? I get errors like:

`Unknown Error] Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘.“ClassName”, “SiteTree_Live”.“LastEdited”, “SiteTree_Live”.“Created”, "SiteTree’ at line 1`

I can see the connection being made in the ProxySQL log but nothing every comes back from it. The site work fine without ProxySQL being in the mix.

If I set the ProxSQL connection to use fast_forward = 1, the Silverstripe site works fine. However, this bypasses the query layer which is what I want to capture.